# Move docker container and its database container to another server

Tags: docker, containers, odoo, odoo-13

I have an odoo:13 container and its corresponding postgres container running in a server. I want to move them to a test server so my test server's data be similar to my original server. how can I do it? I have mounted volumes by the way. (I created docker volumes)

Comment: you can check how export works: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/export/

Answer (score 4):

As you have already mounted the data on to volumes, you will be able to start the containers on a new server using the same docker images using the backup from the old container.

Refer the official guide for [backup-restore-or-migrate-data-volumes](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/#backup-restore-or-migrate-data-volumes).

Comment: can you be more specific? Im new to docker.